# Cohen's d calculation in R

Tags: r, cohens-d

I am using following code to find Cohen's d (means are m1 and m2, standard deviations are s1 and s2 while sample sizes are n1 and n2):

```
lx <- n1- 1
ly <- n2- 1
md  <- abs(m1-m2)        ## mean difference (numerator)
csd <- lx * s1^2 + ly * s2^2
csd <- csd/(lx + ly)
csd <- sqrt(csd)                     ## common sd computation

cd  <- md/csd                        ## cohen's d
cd
```

For the example given on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen.27s_d (men's and women's heights by Aaron et al) I am getting a value of 1.756 while example states the value to be 1.72. Although the difference is small, I want to know if there is some mistake I am making in the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the calculation on the website uses an unweighted estimate of the pooled variance. Try your calculation again with equal ns of any size over 1 and you'll see that the answer is 1.72. You might want to edit the wikipedia page.

As to whether you're doing anything wrong, you're not. However, Cohen's *d* isn't well specified in terms of equation. Always state the equation you used when reporting Cohen's *d*.

Comment: Isn't there one standard equation for Cohen's d? Can you elaborate on this.

Comment: Cohen's *d* was defined as the effect over standard deviation. No equation was given for the standard deviation and you're expected to use a reasonable one given the specifics of a situation. There are a number of ways to do this. Your weighted variance approach is a reasonable one. You may note that the Glass and Hedge calculations on the same page are just variations of what standard deviation to use. They're are all all still estimates of *d*.

Comment: Which is best method for such effect size for non-normal data?

Comment: Ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

In a recent article, we made this R function available which computes Hedges's g (an unbiased version of Cohen's) along with confidence interval:

```
gethedgesg <-function( x1, x2, design = "between", coverage = 0.95) {
  # mandatory arguments are x1 and x2, both a vector of data

  require(psych) # for the functions SD and harmonic.mean.

  # store the columns in a dataframe: more convenient to handle one variable than two
  X <- data.frame(x1,x2)

  # get basic descriptive statistics
  ns  <- lengths(X)
  mns <- colMeans(X)
  sds <- SD(X)

  # get pairwise statistics
  ntilde <- harmonic.mean(ns)
  dmn    <- abs(mns[2]-mns[1])
  sdp    <- sqrt( (ns[1]-1) *sds[1]^2 + (ns[2]-1)*sds[2]^2) / sqrt(ns[1]+ns[2]-2)

  # compute biased Cohen's d (equation 1) 
  cohend <- dmn / sdp

  # compute unbiased Hedges' g (equations 2a and 3)
  eta     <- ns[1] + ns[2] - 2
  J       <- gamma(eta/2) / (sqrt(eta/2) * gamma((eta-1)/2) )
  hedgesg <-  cohend * J

  # compute noncentrality parameter (equation 5a or 5b depending on the design)
  lambda <- if(design == "between") {
    hedgesg * sqrt( ntilde/2)
  } else {
    r <- cor(X)[1,2]
    hedgesg * sqrt( ntilde/(2 * (1-r)) )
  }

  # confidence interval of the hedges g (equations 6 and 7)
  tlow <- qt(1/2 - coverage/2, df = eta, ncp = lambda )
  thig <- qt(1/2 + coverage/2, df = eta, ncp = lambda )

  dlow <- tlow / lambda * hedgesg 
  dhig <- thig / lambda * hedgesg 

  # all done! display the results
  cat("Hedges'g = ", hedgesg, "\n", coverage*100, "% CI = [", dlow, dhig, "]\n")

}
```

It can be used for example with:

```
x1 <- c(53, 68, 66, 69, 83, 91)
x2 <- c(49, 60, 67, 75, 78, 89)

# using the defaults: between design and 95% coverage
gethedgesg(x1, x2)

# changing the defaults explicitely
gethedgesg(x1, x2, design = "within", coverage = 0.90 )
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Denis's helpful answer and to hopefully make this more easily discoverable (I just spent half an hour finding a solution): `gethedgesg()` currently fails with large samples (N > 340ish) - replacing the calculation for J as follows makes the function work more robustly:

`J <- exp ( lgamma(eta/2) - (log(sqrt(eta/2)) + lgamma((eta-1)/2) ) )`

Comment: Seems a good refinement.