# How to calculate Cohen's D in R

Tags: r, effect-size, cohens-d

I want to see if there is a difference in tenure between low performers and high performers. I am using R and I did an ANOVA to test the difference with this code:

```
fit <- aov(Tenure ~ Perf2016, data=df)
summary(fit)
```

Tenure is a continuous variable and Perf2016 is a dichotomous variable. 
I want to calculate Cohen's D but I don't know how. I tried this code, from the Effsize package, but it did not work:

```
cohen.d(df$Tenure, df$Perf2016, pooled=TRUE, paired=FALSE, na.rm=FALSE, 
    hedges.correction = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, noncentral = FALSE)
```

Here is what I got:

```
Cohen's d

d estimate: NA (NA)
95 percent confidence interval:
inf sup 
NA  NA
```

Can someone explain to me how to calculate it? Please note that I am a beginner with R.

Comment: Why not do it by hand using the code in this Q&A http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151781/cohens-d-calculation-in-r?rq=1 which would also give you the benefit of knowing exactly what you did.

Comment: @mdewey: I will try that as well. How do I get the N from each group? When I did the ANOVA, I did not get that information. Thanks!

Comment: table(dt$Perf2016) but really you should do that sort of descriptive first as it often answers the question of why you are not getting the results you expected.

Answer (score 2):

Veronique,

My first guess is that your data might not be formatted as numeric, so you need to check that first.  You can convert like this:

```
df$Tenure<-as.numeric(df$Tenure)
```

You may need to convert other data into numeric as well, but without seeing your data I can't tell.  You might also want to check for missing values in your data, and you can do that by looking at the distribution:

```
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
count(df$Tenure)
```

Check the results to see about missing data.

Comment: Ben, I converted my 2 variables as numeric. If it helps, I checked if I was able to od an histogram and I am. So I believe this means they are indeed numerci? Also, tenure has no missing values, but Perf2016 has some. I tried the Cohen's D formula again and it did not work.

Comment: You can try df2<-df[complete.cases(df), ]  to ensure missing cases are removed